# How do I access and assign values in a nested dictionary with the inner key being a custom class?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am trying to access and assign values based on the Key of my inner dictionary, which happens to be a custom object, PlanTier, which has 2 properties, PlanName and Tiers.

The problems start here:
curEnrollByEnrolledOrWaived[group.Key][waivedPlanTier] =
                            enrByGroupAndPlan[group.Key][waivedPlanTier];

Note that while dictionaries "curEnrollByEnrolledOrWaived" and "enrByGroupAndPlan" are prefilled (as input parameters), the PlanTier object "waivedPlanTier" (which I am trying to use (as the key) to find the corresponding value in those dictionaries) is initialized in this function.

I have read that the issue is caused by object reference, thus the 2 dictionaries which indeed contain the key which has the same properties as "waivedPlanTier". Another thing,

QUESTIONS: 
Is it possible to grab the corresponding value of the inner dictionary by equating the key of the inner dictionary with "waivedPlanTier"? If so, how can I do it?

If it is not possible, are there other any methods that I can use to access and assign the values based on key using "waivedPlanTier"?

Here is the code:

```
        private static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<PlanTier, double>> PopulateEnrollOrWaived(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<PlanTier, double>> fullListByGroupAndEnrStatus, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<PlanTier, double>> enrByGroupAndPlan, List<string> distinctTierList) (Dictionary<string, Dictionary<PlanTier, double>> fullListByGroupAndEnrStatus
        , Dictionary<string, Dictionary<PlanTier, double>> enrByGroupAndPlan
        , List<string> distinctTierList)
    {

        Dictionary<string, Dictionary<PlanTier, double>> curEnrollByEnrolledOrWaived =
            fullListByGroupAndEnrStatus.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.ToDictionary(y => y.Key, y => y.Value));

        PlanTierComparer comparer = new PlanTierComparer();

        foreach (var group in curEnrollByEnrolledOrWaived)
        {
            foreach (var tier in distinctTierList)
            {
                if (enrByGroupAndPlan.ContainsKey(group.Key))
                {
                    PlanTier waivedPlanTier = new PlanTier(Enums.Literals.WaivedPlanName, tier);
                    PlanTier enrolledPlanTier = new PlanTier("Enrolled", tier);

                    var test = curEnrollByEnrolledOrWaived[group.Key];

                    var test1 = test.Keys.Where(x => x.Equals(waivedPlanTier));                                      

                    curEnrollByEnrolledOrWaived[group.Key][waivedPlanTier] =
                        enrByGroupAndPlan[group.Key][waivedPlanTier];

                    curEnrollByEnrolledOrWaived[group.Key][enrolledPlanTier] =
                        enrByGroupAndPlan[group.Key].Values.Sum()
                        - curEnrollByEnrolledOrWaived[group.Key][waivedPlanTier];
                }
            }

        }
        return curEnrollByEnrolledOrWaived;
    }
```

Comment: *"the 2 dictionaries which indeed contain the key which has the same properties as "waivedPlanTier""* - But are those instances *equal*?  Have you overridden `.Equals()` and `.GetHashCode()` in that class to define equality?  The default is reference equality, which has nothing to do with property values.

Comment: Hi, they have the same property values but are not the same instance of the object. I have overwritten the .Equals () and .GetHashCode () but they seem to only work when I am using them explicitly. For example when I have bool isEqual = waivedPlanTier.Equals (waivedPlanTier2), isEqual is correct in this case. But when I try to access the dictionary using waivedPlanTier, it doesn't seem to recognise that one of the key in the dict is actually equal to waivedPlanTier.

Comment: That's odd.  Can you show your implementation for those on that class?  What if you also implement the `IQualityComparer<YourClass>` interface on your class?  (Or on another class related to it, keeping that concern separated if you prefer.)

Answer (score 0):

By default reference types are checked for equality by reference: `new PlanTier("plan2", "tier1").Equals(new PlanTier("plan2", "tier1"))` always evaluates to false. As a consequence, if you use a reference type as a dictionary key, the lookup will be done by reference, as well.

When you need lookup by value, you have basically two options:

- Implement an [IEqualityComparer<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1) like this:

  ```
  class PlanTierComparer : IEqualityComparer<PlanTier>
  {
      public static readonly PlanTierComparer Instance = new PlanTierComparer();

      PlanTierComparer() { }

      public bool Equals(PlanTier x, PlanTier y)
      {
          if (x == null && y == null)
              return true;

          if (x == null || y == null)
              return false;

          return x.PlanName == y.PlanName && x.Tiers == y.Tiers;
      }

      public int GetHashCode(PlanTier obj)
      {
          return obj != null ? obj.PlanName.GetHashCode() ^ obj.Tiers.GetHashCode() : 0;
      }
  }
  ```

  (I assumed that *PlanName* and *Tiers* properties cannot be null.)

  And create your dictionaries using this comparer:

  ```
  var pt1 = new PlanTier("plan1", "tier1");
  var pt2 = new PlanTier("plan1", "tier2");
  var pt3 = new PlanTier("plan2", "tier1");

  // Dictionary ctor example
  var dic1 = new Dictionary<PlanTier, double>(PlanTierComparer.Instance) { { pt1, 1.0 }, { pt2, 2.0 }, { pt3, 3.0 } };

  // ToDictionary() example
  var dic2 = new[]
  {
      new KeyValuePair<PlanTier, double>(pt1, 1.0),
      new KeyValuePair<PlanTier, double>(pt2, 2.0),
      new KeyValuePair<PlanTier, double>(pt3, 3.0),
  }.ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value, PlanTierComparer.Instance);
  ```
- Or just make your key type implement [IEquatable<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1):

  ```
  class PlanTier : IEquatable<PlanTier>
  {
      public PlanTier(string planName, string tiers)
      {
          PlanName = planName ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(planName));
          Tiers = tiers ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(tiers));
      }

      public string PlanName { get; }
      public string Tiers { get; }

      public override bool Equals(object obj)
      {
          return obj is PlanTier other ? Equals(other) : false;
      }

      public override int GetHashCode()
      {
          return PlanName.GetHashCode() ^ Tiers.GetHashCode();
      }

      public bool Equals(PlanTier other)
      {
          if (other == null)
              return false;

          return PlanName == other.PlanName && Tiers == other.Tiers;
      }
  }
  ```

  You need to override the *GetHashCode* and *Equals(object)* methods, as well to make this work. (Actually, you can get along by overriding only these two methods, you don't necessarily have to implement *IEquatable<T>*. However, it is advisable to do so for better performance, especially in the case of value types (structs) to avoid boxing.)

One more thing to keep in mind when using complex types as dictionary keys: key objects should be *immutable*! In other words, the state of a key object shouldn't change after its creation because this could result in a changed hash code which would break dictionary's functionality.